# Easily reference cells in offset

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I have a worksheet with many formulas that look one cell above, or to the right. If I use ctrl-D to populate rows, the formulas are updated correctly (so =B1 + A2 in B2 becomes =B2+A3 in B3). But when I insert in between rows, things get messed (so inserting a row above B3, moving it to B4 makes its formula become =B2+A4, which is not what I want)

So I thought to create a CellAbove and CellRight formulas (so I can write =CellAbove() + CellRight()). How can I do that?

My attempt:

```
Function CellAbove()
   CellAbove = [Address(Row() - 1, Column())].Value
End Function
```

doesn't work.

UPDATE:
The function below works, but cells that have it are not updated:

```
Function CellAbove()
   CellAbove = Range([Address(Row() - 1, Column())])
End Function
```

So if A1 has 2 and A2 has =CellAbove() then A2 will show 2. But if now I change A1 to 3, then A2 will still show 2

Comment: I want to reference cells above or right of the one with the formula. using absolute references means ctrl-d doesn't work for populating many cells

Comment: Why do you want VBA for this? In two clicks you can set everything back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function worked, and it seemed all you needed was it to recalculate when you insert rows.
you said:

"but cells that have it are not updated"

User Defined Functions are by default NOT volatile so they won't automatically recalculate.
You could change your existing function to this.

```
Function CellAbove()
 Application.Volatile (True)
 CellAbove = Range([Address(Row() - 1, Column())])
End Function
```

This can impact performance, but seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: I think it does what you want. I only meant volatile functions cause recalculation and if you have a huge file with lots of that it can be in issue. For instance thousands of cells

Answer (score 2):

=INDIRECT("R"&ROW()-1&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE) would work as a function.

Suppose you're on B2.  Then the bit inside the brackets would evaluate to R1C2.  The INIDRECT function would then calculate what is at row 1 column 2 (you need the FALSE to ensure you're using the R1C1 style of cell address).

I'm sure you could do something simpler using:

OFFSET(CurrentCell,-1,0)

but I can't see how you can refer to the current cell.

Comment: The point was to have a VBA function. How would your formula look when adding two cells (one above, one below)?

Answer (score 0):

***Functions from yours***

```
Function CellAbove()
   CellAbove = Range([Address(Row() - 1, Column())])
End Function

Function CellRight()
   CellRight = Range([Address(Row(), Column() + 1)])
End Function
```

***May be called as***

```
Function test000000()
    ActiveCell = CellAbove + CellRight
End Sub
```

Comment: But, as I wrote, I can't use these functions as part of cell formula.

Comment: You only could use this function as a whole not just a part of another function. Use this syntax ``=<name_of_xls_file>!<name_of_function>`` to use any custom function. Look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2007-HA010218996.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using built-in Excel functions like INDIRECT, ADDRESS, ROW, and COLUMN, as in...

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))
```

...for the cell above, or...

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1))
```

...for the cell to the right.

Another approach, again using built-in capability, would be to use the OFFSET function.  For example, in cell B2, you could enter the formula...

```
=OFFSET(B2,-1,0)
```

...for the cell above, or...

```
=OFFSET(B2,0,1)
```

...for the cell to the right.  It looks like a circular reference, but it's not, since you are not referencing the value of the same cell, only its address.

Either way, you more or less lose the ability to use the "Trace Dependents" and "Trace Precedents" features, since each cell essentially references only itself.

Comment: This doesn't scale when the formula needs to do real calculations and reference many cells

Answer (score 0):

Followup on my comment. We don't need vba for this :)

After you have inserted the blank row

**Step 1**

Drag the formula down from `B2` to `B3` or simply select `B3` and press `CTL D`

**Step 2**

Select Cell `B3`. Do an Autofill by double clicking on the bottom right corner of the cell.

[image]

Comment: I wrote in the question the problem with ctrl-d which is that if I now copy row 2 and insert above row 3, the formula in row 3 will  be wrong. if it started with =B2+A3 it will become =B3+A5 (should be =B4+A5)

Comment: I know it will be wrong :) Please re-read the above post again :)

Comment: sorry, didn't work. maybe for a single cell it works but i need it for a row with 8 such formulas. selecting the row and double clicking the corner did nothing.

Comment: Seems like you are not aware how double clicking works :) Anyways, you can also drag the formula down.

Comment: :-). I tried double clicking until my mouse begged for mercy.

Comment: No I didn't mean that. Double clicking the "Fill Handle" works on a logic :) Excel will stop copying the formula when it reaches a row with a blank cell (in the same column or the adjacent column). In the snapshot that I posted above, the formulas will get copied till cell B11 as B12 is empty.

Comment: It works for a single cell, but I have a row with several such formulas. Clicking each is a drag ;-)